# unable access the inner nested datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my web application , there is `datalist`, which is inside another `datalist`.
i want to access that `datalist` . for this purpose i written this code

```
DataList dl = (DataList)dlPro_Details.FindControl("dlFeatures");
```

but when i try to run the application , then it throw **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
then set the debug the point to it , the i found my `object` dl is `null` .

i have also tried to use `ItemDataBound`

```
protected void dlPro_Details_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 8;
        string getFeatures = "";
        con = new SqlConnection(str);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select * from Products where Pro_id=" + id + "", con);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            getFeatures = dr.GetValue(11).ToString();
        }
        string se = ",";
        List<string> l1 = new List<string>();
        string[] featurs = getFeatures.Split(se.ToCharArray());
        for (int i = 0; i < featurs.Length; i++)
        {
            l1.Add(featurs[i]);
        }
        DataList dl = (DataList)dlPro_Details.FindControl("dlFeatures");

        dl.DataSource = l1;
        dl.DataBind();
    }
```

**dlPro_Details** is my parent datalist

this is my complete  code

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlPro_Details" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dlPro_Details_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="pro_img">
                                        <asp:Image ID="proImg" runat="server" Width="230" Height="300" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Image") %>' />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="rating">
                                        give rate<br />hello
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="vertical-align:top">
                                    <div class="Pro_name">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="otherInfo">
                                      <table style="width:100%;padding:8px 12px 0 12px;">
                                          <tr>
                                              <td>
                                                  <asp:Label ID="lblWarenty" runat="server" Text='<%#"Warranty :  "+Eval("Warranty") %>'></asp:Label>
                                              </td>
                                              <td>
                                                  <asp:Label ID="lblBrand" runat="server" Text='<%#"By :  "+Eval("Brand") %>'></asp:Label>
                                              </td>
                                              <td style="float:right">
                                                  Rating 
                                              </td>
                                          </tr>
                                      </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="features">
                                       <div class="feat_Head">
                                           <asp:Label ID="lblFeatHead" runat="server" Text="Features"></asp:Label>
                                       </div>
                                        <div class="feat_containt">
                                            <asp:DataList ID="dlFeatures" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
                                                <ItemTemplate> 
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblFeatures" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:DataList>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Show your markup of DataList

Comment: i have edited my question . now you can see my complete markup for datalist.

Comment: why you want to access it on page load.give some description so we can give you some other ways to perform action what you want.@Amit

Comment: I suspect the problem is that because it is in a datalist it is not a single control you are getting there. Not sure of the solution to that offhand though sadly.

Comment: @SumitPathak: as you can see from my code , i just want to assign the diffent data to label of inner datalaist . so  i want to access it on pageload . if you can suggest me diffrent idea to assign the list to inner datalist , so that when my parent datalist laod then inner datalist should also be loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the reference to the current item using one of the arguments, and from there you can access any nested control:

```
protected void dlPro_Details_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var innerDL = e.Item.FindControl("dlFeatures") as DataList;
        if(innerDL != null)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it showing == ItemType.type ||
doesn't exist in current context

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've corrected the code. Its supposed to be `ListItemType.Item` or likewise.

Comment: yes i got that . 
but sir now how can i bind that list item to inner datalist label.
i want to show the data of list  , to show in label of datalist.

Comment: I knew this was the next problem. :) Plz refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)